# Intellij sbt plugin with project definition in project/Build.scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am using the following `sbt` project structure in Intelli-j 13.1

```
.
├── build.sbt
├── project
│   ├── Build.scala
│   ├── plugins.sbt
├── src
│   ├── main
│   └── test
└── target
```

My `built.sbt` is very simple, I just declare some dependencies.

My `project/Build.scala` is a bit more complex, it defines a new Project using:

lazy val RiepeteKernel = Project(     id = "riepete-kernel",     base = file("."),     settings = defaultSettings     )

Intellij does not seem to like it. It setups two additional modules in the project settings, like this:

[image]

And when I try to compile my project, I get the following error:

```
  Error:scalac: Output path /home/simao/code/riepete/project/target/idea-test-classes is shared between: 
  Module 'riepete-build' tests, Module 'riepete-kernel-build' tests Output path /home/simao/code/riepete/project/target/idea-classes 
  is shared between: Module 'riepete-build' production,
  Module 'riepete-kernel-build' production   Please configure separate output
  paths to proceed with the compilation.
  TIP: you can use Project Artifacts to combine compiled classes if needed.
```

Since I just need my extra project to run `sbt dist` on the console, if I delete the two additional modules that intellij creates everything works, but I need to do this every time I restart intellij.

Is there a way to make intellij not create these two additional modules?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on you version of `sbt` but at least in version `0.13.x` you can use [`project` macro](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html) like this:

```
lazy val riepete = project.in( file(".") )
```

This way IntelliJ idea won't create an additional module.

You can even put this is your `build.sbt`. According to my experience in most cases you can just maintain a simple `build.sbt` file, especially with latest versions of `sbt`. Anyway I guess keeping it in one place makes sense: `build.sbt` or `Build.scala` in `project` folder.

If you project or sub-project folder name contains `-` or other characters, you can always use back ticks, for example:

```
lazy val `riepete-project` = project
```

in this case you don't even need to use `.in(file(....` as the macro will pick the files from the right folder based on the name of the module.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to add some `Settings` to the project if it's created using that macro?
Why doesn't intellij pick up the project if it's defined like that? Thanks

Comment: Of course. It's possible. You can call `settings` method on project and add your settings: `lazy val riepete = project.in(file(".")).settings(....).settings()`, or you can use normal way. By normal way I mean adding setting keys to you `build.sbt`, for example: `libraryDependencies += ....`. All these settings will be picked up. Try refreshing the project from `SBT` tab (You can find it in right sidebar in IntelliJ IDEA). If not working you can import the project again. Removing `.idea` folder and reimporting will be the last solution.

Comment: Thanks.  It looks as though IntelliJ scala plugin is taking the actual name of the val you assign project to and creates a module for it.  If you call it "root" like the docs in sbt say, but call the project something else, then it will create conflicting modules.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is not to use IntellJ's SBT import feature and generate its files using the [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin. Note that you'll need to rerun it on SBT project changes (dependency addition/removal, etc.).

Another is to turn off auto-import option when importing the SBT project, then remove the extra modules in the IDEA project structure dialog.

Comment: If I use `sbt-idea`, do I need to disable something in intellij? I didn't use sbt-idea before because seems like a bit outdated, but maybe I am wrong. I'll try it out. thank you

Comment: No, you don't need to disable anything if you mean a plugin, but as mentioned in the answer you need to disable the auto-import option. After generating idea module files by `idea-gen`, just open the project from IntelliJ IDEA (Don't `Import` but `Open`).